# React Router Dom V6 do not load Styled Components Styles

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, styled-components

In a React project, I am using React Router Dom v6 to create routing. Some routes are public, and some ones are private. For this logic I have done:

```js
function Private ({ signed }: Control): JSX.Element {
  return signed ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to={DEFAULT_PUBLIC_ROUTE} />
}

function Public ({ signed }: Control): JSX.Element {
  return signed ? <Navigate to={DEFAULT_PRIVATE_ROUTE} /> : <Outlet />
};
```

The problem is: when I try to go to a private route without I am signed, I back correctly for the DEFAULT_PUBLIC_ROUTE, but the page do not load the CSS of the components created with styled-component.
I have tried create a component with inline style like:

```html
<div style={{ background: 'red' }}>SOME TEXT FOR TESTING</div>
```

and this component has been succefull loading the CSS.
Any one know what is happening?

**Test Case:**

**Step 1:** Accessing login screen
[Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4o1Z.png)

**Step 2:** Trying go to an private route
[Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dCi4.png)

**Step 3:** Accessing a private route and be redirect
[Step 3 and final state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B35yO.png)

And when back to route "/", the page do not have CSS, but have the HTML structure.

I am trying access a unallowed route and back for default route with CSS render correctly.

Comment: Could you [edit] your post to include all the relevant code you are working with and have an issue using as part of a complete [mcve]? We can't really address issues in code we can't see. Does the issue persist/reproduce if you use in-app navigation to navigate to the different routes versus reloading the page by manual URL manipulation in the address bar?

Comment: Of course. I will create create a codepen project to reproduce. But answering your questions: this error not occour when you try access private page with hooks like useNavigate. The CSS is loaded correctly. Only occour when you try manipulate the address bar. Or when you are in an private route, trying reload the page, and click to logout, what will remove your signed status and the Navigate component will redirect you to the DEFAULT_PUBLIC_ROUTE. Apparently, for the Navigate component render the CSS, the application should has been loaded the component before at least one time.